# How to export JMeter LatenciesOverTime report?

Tags: jmeter

I'm using the JMeter Plugins and I'd like to know if someone could teach me how can I export the LatenciesOverTime report using the GUI? I'm able to create the report; however, the file that should output the Latency report only has the information from the "Simple Data Writer".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I just had to make a right click over the graph -> Export to CSV. The UI isn't very intuitive.